# Troubles creating a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table:

[image]

I was wondering if there's a chance to write a query that can retrieve distinct values from "name" column and the latest date for each name value.

For the given data, the desired output is:

```
╔═════════╦════════════╗
║  Name   ║    Date    ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ Foo     ║ 2012-12-11 ║
║ Bar     ║ 2012-12-26 ║
║ Foo Bar ║ 2012-12-18 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, MAX(date) FROM tableName GROUP BY name;
```

This is retrieving all items from the `name` column (without using `distinct`), and is grouping them so we can get the maximum number. `group by` allows other nifty tricks like `COUNT()`, `MIN()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name, MAX(date) date
FROM tableName
GROUP BY name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31040/2)